# one hot representation behaving differently for two cases

Tags: python, numpy

I am using following function for one hot representation.

```
def dense_to_one_hot(labels_dense, num_classes=2):
    num_labels = labels_dense.shape[0]
    print("num_labels")
    index_offset = numpy.arange(num_labels) * num_classes
    print("index_offset: ",index_offset )
    labels_one_hot = numpy.zeros((num_labels, num_classes))
    print(labels_one_hot.shape)
    print(labels_dense.ravel())
    labels_one_hot.flat[index_offset + labels_dense.ravel()] = 1
    print(labels_one_hot)
    return labels_one_hot
```

I am getting the error of unsupported iterator index.

```
train_label_1 = np.load(os.path.join("Input","train_label.npy"))
    train_label = train_label_1[0:10]
    print("train_label")
    print(train_label)
    labels_one_hot = dense_to_one_hot(train_label)
    print("label_one_hot")
    print(labels_one_hot)
```

When I print train_label, I get following result.

```
[0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
```

When I convert this into numpy array and then call `dense_to_one_hot`  function it works fine But When I simply load train label from file and call this function it starts giving me error of `unsupported iterator index`. Can some one please guide me how to fix it.

Comment: There are indentation errors in your code. I bet someone would help you if you made your example more minimal. As it stands there's no input data so it's impossible to reproduce the bug

Comment: I fixed your code formatting but you still need input data and expected output